# Simple Multiple Choice

Tags: math, prolog

I want to ask about my multiple choice program that I made. I confuse how to store a value continuously, so I can take a conclusion in the end of program, based on sum of the value that already store.

```
start :- program.
program :- 
     write('This is question number 1'),nl,
     write('A'),nl,
     write('B'),nl,
     write('C'),nl,
     read(Choice),nl,
     ( 
        %case1
        Choice='a'->nl, 
        =================================
        A = A + 1  <--- Right Here,
        And then go to Question 2.
        =================================

        %case2
        Choice='b'->nl, 
        =================================
        B = B + 1  <--- Right Here,
        And then go to Question 2.
        =================================

        %case3
        Choice='c'->nl, 
        =================================
        C = C + 1  <--- Right Here,
        And then go to Question 2.
        =================================

        %case_default
        write('Wrong Code')
    ).
```

So I can take a conclusion like this,

```
===================================
if B < A > C then you're an A.
if A < B > C then you're a B.
if A < C > B then you're a C.
===================================
```

Thanks you very much before :)

Comment: In your `A = A + 1` expression, where does `A` come from initially (same question for `B`, `C`, and `D`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible ways to store values. What you probably think of - storing some counters and updating them on given answers - can lead to some complicated situations. Example of code working with counters:

```
question('Choose a, b or c: ').
question('Choose again a, b or c: ').
question('Think before you choose a, b, or c: ').

ask :-
    findall(Q, question(Q), Questions),
    ask_and_count([0,0,0], [A,B,C], Questions),
    max_list([A,B,C], Max),
    nth1(Index,[A,B,C],Max),
    nth1(Index,[a,b,c],Answer),
    print('You''re a(n) '), print(Answer), nl.
ask_and_count(Count, Count, []) :-
    print('Thank you, that''s all questions!'), nl, !.
ask_and_count(InCount, OutCount, [Q | Questions]) :-
    print(Q),
    read_abc(Ans),
    increase(Ans, InCount, NewCount),
    ask_and_count(NewCount, OutCount, Questions).
read_abc(A) :-
    read(A),
    member(A, [a,b,c]),
    !.
read_abc(A) :-
    print('Only a, b and c are accepted! Answer again: '),
    read_abc(A).
increase(a, [A, B, C], [X, B, C]) :- X is A + 1.
increase(b, [A, B, C], [A, X, C]) :- X is B + 1.
increase(c, [A, B, C], [A, B, X]) :- X is C + 1.
```

Sample input and output:

```
?- ask.
Choose a, b or c: b.
Choose again a, b or c: c.
Think before you choose a, b, or c: c.
Thank you, that's all questions!
You're a(n) c
```

Maybe I can inspire you to do it another way, which in my opinion is more "prologish" as it relies on lists and leads to simpler code:

```
question('Choose a, b or c: ').
question('Choose again a, b or c: ').
question('Think before you choose a, b, or c: ').

read_abc(A, Choices) :-
    read(A),
    member(A, Choices),
    !.
read_abc(A, Choices) :-
    print('Only '), print(Choices), print(' are accepted! Try again: '),
    read_abc(A, Choices).
ask(Answers) :-
    findall(Ans, (question(Q), print(Q), read_abc(Ans, [a,b,c])), Answers).

start :-
    ask(Answers),
    print(Answers).
```

Sample input and output:

```
?- start.
Choose a, b or c: c.
Choose again a, b or c: b.
Think before you choose a, b, or c: c.
[c,b,c]
true.
```

After you have all answers in a list, you can simply count occurences of every answer.

Other way of storing choices is by using `assert` and `retract` predicates. [Expert systems do that](http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog/02usingprolog.htm#rememberingtheanswer). When using assert and retract you can use some predicates like global variables known from other programming languages.

Comment: it's work @Grzegorz , thanks a lot for your example. but I have another bug, and I don't know how to fix it.
I close my SWI Prolog console when my program not finished yet, but it's generated an infinity loops till a certain period of time.
I use switch case for my program, I'm sorry I can't give my code, because it has many lines, and different language, I use Bahasa.

Comment: @ElIllumaneti, wihtout knowing your code I can't do much to help you. Try asking this as new question on Stack Overflow and paste your code.